# What's the efficient way to insert elements from array to existing Html element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have heard few approaches:

1. I could simply iterate through 20k elements and do appendChild.
2. I could insert All items into newly created div in js and then just put that div into parent dom.
3. Is there any other approach? Copy html wholesale?

However, I am confused on how to do 2. What is the best way to move all child element from div A to div B without iterating over all of them.

Comment: Please show the exact structure of source and target elements.

Comment: @cFreed here ` arr = [ domElement , domElement , domElement , domElement .....] `

Comment: Use jQuery.  It's designed for exactly this kind of thing.

Comment: [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment)

Comment: @DaveKaye i'd in production, but i am trying to understand behind the scenes myself better

Comment: Nothing wrong with that!  I knew JavaScript for so many years before jQuery came along that I can't imagine what we did without it.

Comment: @DaveKaye i am opposite i started with jquery and bee learning js since then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use document fragment which appends all at one moment

```
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  fragment.appendChild(...)
  fragment.appendChild(...)
  ...
  element.appendChild(fragment)
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [this source](http://moduscreate.com/efficient-dom-and-css/) the fastest is to simply iterate through the elements and append them.

Far better than creating a random div is to create a document fragment and append to that fragment. Then, said fragment can be added to the dom

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment()
arr.forEach(el => fragment.appendChild(el))
element.appendChild(fragment)
```

I made a [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/dom-array-append-so/3) that contains an experiment about which of these two are faster. It appears that using document fragment is the same as raw append with my limited test (one browser, one OS)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just using **[cloneNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)** in deep mode:

```
// Copy the element and its child nodes
var cln = itm.cloneNode(true);

// Append the cloned element to the new div with id="new_div"
document.getElementById("new_div").innerHTML(cln);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: wont this result in additional element in destination element

Comment: eleA -> '' empty "  & eleB -> "children, children, children" ......after this...... eleA -> '' eleB -> "children, children, children" "  & eleB -> "children, children, children"